# How to make React Service as Singleton, Injectable, and Redux Connected

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

## Summary

I am writing a **React-Redux** application, and would like to create a **service** that can be accessed across multiple components, with the following characteristics:

1. **Singleton** (just gets instantiated once across the entire
   application)
2. **Injectable** (can be injected into, and used by, multiple components across the application)
3. **Redux Connected** (can access the entire Redux state tree & received updates to state changes)

## Code Example

The type of solution I have in mind, would allow me to inject a service int a React Component, and use in the following way:

```
{ featureAvailabilityService.isAvailable('myFeature') && (<MyFeature />) }
```

## Ideas

I have read about **High Order Components**, **Hooks**, and the **Context API**. There are also some interesting libraries, such as [Unstated](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated), and [Redux-Logic](https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic). I feel like the best answer probably lies somewhere between these, but could use some guidance to put me on the right track.

## Use Case

In this instance, I would like to create a reusable service, which has methods to determine the availability of certain features. This involves relatively complex logic  based on System, Tenant, and User configuration and state. It also requires the service to have access to state from several different parts of the application. It will also be reused broadly across the application.

## Why Yet Another React Service Question?

I realize there are already a lot of similar questions to this, usually from people with an Angular background, looking for the React equivalent to an Angular Service. However, I have not yet found an answer that provides for the above three criteria... or at least not one that I understood.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: so you are using Redux already. what if you encapsulate that logic into redux module? what's the difference between your expectations from 'service' and redux module?

Comment: The piece of logic I would like to encapsulate is relevant to multiple different areas of the application, and in turn, multiple different Redux modules. 

I am really hoping to create something like the following: 
`featureFlagService.isFeatureAvailable('FeatureName')`, which can be injected into react components to aid rendering across the app. However, the service needs access to the full state tree to determine this.

Comment: states/store is meant to keep `availableFeatures.featureName=true` - ready values to be used as props, no need to call for them/calculate on demand - reducers are for keeping them up to date